# Can I select the shortest field name with GROUP BY (MySql)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, group-by, where-clause

Let's say, I have 2 product names: dead space and dead space limited edition, and I want to group them by "product_name" to select "dead space" in a mysql query. So I want the query to select the "product_name" with the shortest string if the where caluse is "product_name LIKE '%dead space%'".

Thanks a lot,

Comment: instead of `like` use `=`

Comment: yes, this could work with "dead space", but I'll search for games with "dead" or just "space". Thanks,

Comment: @Krishna - what?  He specifically doesn't want an exact match, so `=` isn't going to work.  Pabola - if you're inputting things like `"dead"`, do you want it to include, say `"Left 4 Dead"` in the search?  If you're trying to group by series/release you need a different setup query.

Comment: Sure-sure, I have keywords for links: like "stick of truth", my query search for games with this keyword and I can make a link (to a search page with this keyword) and the link's title will be the shortest product_name (if there's a limited edition, I don't want to have 2 links). If I change/add something in the product_name (like a ":" or "-") I want to change the link's title automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you may try `LENGTH()`.

```
 select product_name ,length(product_name) as the_length from your_table 
 where product_name LIKE '%dead space%'
 ORDER BY  length(product_name)
 limit 1
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/45fd7/5)

Comment: He probably only wants one record, but this looks closest.

Comment: @GordonLinoff do what you see it nice gordon :) , its all yours :) . i just didnt see that he want one result. anyway thanks for the up+ . edited also the demo

Answer (score 1):

Please try this query

```
 select * from table where product_name LIKE '%dead space%'
 HAVING length(product_name ) = min(length(product_name ))
```

Comment: If this works, it is a coincidence.  The `having` clause chooses an arbitrary row for the `length(product_name)`.  It will definitely not work in all cases.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I checked it with two rows in database one title longer and one shorter. and it picked shorter one.

Comment: . . Put them in a different order.  Also, you can try these things out on SQL Fiddle.